# Rotate a hypercube

Tags: code-golf, math, graphical-output, geometry

### Introduction

A hypercube/tesseract is the 4 dimensional equivalent of a normal cube. It's made by taking a cube net, extending it to the 3rd dimension, then – using the 4th dimension – folding it into a hypercube. It's basically a cube, where each side is a cube.

To create a hypercube, you need 16 4d vectors (a vector with an `x`, a `y`, a `z` and a `w` component). These vectors are the following:

```
A(0, 0, 0, 0); B(1, 0, 0, 0); C(1, 0, 1, 0); D(0, 0, 1, 0); E(0, 1, 0, 0); F(1, 1, 0, 0); G(1, 1, 1, 0); H(0, 1, 1, 0); 
I(0, 0, 0, 1); J(1, 0, 0, 1); K(1, 0, 1, 1); L(0, 0, 1, 1); M(0, 1, 0, 1); N(1, 1, 0, 1); O(1, 1, 1, 1); P(0, 1, 1, 1);
```

The hypercube has 24 faces. The following list contains all of them (every group marks a quad):

```
ABFE, CDHG, BCGF, DAEH, DCBA, FEHG
IJNM, KLPO, JKON, LIMP, LKJI, PMNO
ABJI, DCKL, BCKJ, DAIL, FEMN, GHPO, FGON, EHPM, EAIM, BFNJ, CGOK, HDLP
```

With all this information, you technically have a hypercube in code. To rotate this, you need 6 different matrices for each rotational plane, one for the YZ, XZ, XY, XW, YW and ZW planes. After you have every matrix, you need to multiply the cube's vertices with them.

The following images show the structure of each matrix:

For the rotation on the YZ plane:

[image]

For the rotation on the XZ plane:

[image]

For the rotation on the XY plane:

[image]

For the rotation on the XW plane:

[image]

For the rotation on the YW plane:

[image]

For the rotation on the ZW plane:

[image]

The rotations get applied in this order.

After all this, you have a rotated hypercube. Now you need to draw it. You should use an orthogonal projection combined with a perspective projection to send `(x, y, z, w)` to `(2x/(2+z), 2y/(2+z))`.

### Input

Your input is 6 integers between 0 (inclusively) and 360 (exclusively). These represent the rotations in degrees on the different rotational planes of the hypercube.

### Output

Your output should be a single image containing the hypercube. The display can be a rasterized image, a vector image or an ASCII art. The output image should be at least 100 * 100 pixels, and the cube needs to take up at least 50% of the screen. Any default image output format is allowed.

### Test cases

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

[image]

```
0 0 0 0 0 30
```

[image]

```
30 0 0 0 0 30
```

[image]

```
0 0 0 30 30 30
```

[image]

```
45 45 45 0 0 0
```

[image]

```
45 45 45 45 45 45
```

[image]

Open the images in a new tab, to see them in full size.

### Rules

- Default rules apply
- Standard loopholes are forbidden
- Shortest code in bytes wins

Comment: Why did you nuke the other post?

Comment: @EᴀsᴛᴇʀʟʏIʀᴋ I posted it in the chat for a last review

Comment: @Bálint oh okay.

Comment: As I've pointed out on two separate occasions in the sandbox, the description of projection for display is incomplete because it assumes that the object to be projected is 3-dimensional whereas it is in fact, obviously, 4-dimensional.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Maybe it's an orthogonal projection into 3 dimensions followed by a perspective projection into 2? :/

Comment: @Blue The projection is not the main part of the challenge, you simply use the x and y positions of the vertex, to draw it on the screen.

Comment: Trippy. I like the output when all the rotations are 45 degrees.

Comment: If @Bálint confirms @beaker’s comment, I’ll vote to reopen

Comment: @Lynn I confirm

Comment: @Lynn & Bálint, I think it would be more challenging to require `([x,y]/z)/w`.

Comment: @beaker The challenge is not about the projection

Comment: The face `IJUM` on the second line, what's `U`?

Comment: @luserdroog I think the 'U' must be 'N'.

Comment: Not a big deal, buf: the example XZ rotation matrix has a few lower-case thetas that look odd with all the capital ones around them.

Comment: "basically a cube, where each side is a cube.", that describes a 3d shape.

Comment: @AshwinGupta no, the sides of a 3d cube are *squares*, i.e. 2d shapes, polygons. A cube the sides of which are cubes is an effort to somehow convey this inherently unimaginable object, relating a bit to common sense. At least you can imagine the topology by fusing cubes to the faces of a cube in 3d...

Comment: @AndrasDeak ok I suppose I get what you are saying. It's just hard to conceptualize a shape since we can only understand up to 3D as humans.

Comment: @Bálint Thanks for the challenge, I enjoyed it. Hopefully we'll get more answers and different approaches. :D

Comment: Okay, this may be sort of a dumb question, but what do Big-O and Theta stand for in the matrices?

Comment: @R.Kap the big "O" is the big theta, I just messed up the formatting where there's a small theta. They mean the angle on that plane.

Comment: The list of faces includes `IJUM` but there is no `U` vector. What is that supposed to be?

Comment: @user1472751 fixed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Octave, <s>474</s> <s>433</s> 429 bytes

```
function H(a,b,c,d,e,f) C=@cosd;S=@sind;R=[1,0,0,0;0,C(e),0,-S(e);0,-S(e)*S(f),C(f),-C(e)*S(f);0,S(e)*C(f),S(f),C(e)*C(f)]*[C(c)*C(d),-S(c)*C(d),0,S(d);S(c),C(c),0,0;0,0,1,0;-C(c)*S(d),S(c)*S(d),0,C(d)]*[C(b),S(a)*S(b),C(a)*S(b),0;0,C(a),-S(a),0;-S(b),S(a)*C(b),C(a)*C(b),0;0,0,0,1]*(dec2bin(0:15)'-48.5);Z=R(3,:)+2;R=2*R./Z;Q=[1,2,10,12,11,9,10,14,16,12,4,8,16,15,11,3,7,15,13,9,1,5,13,14,6,8,7,5,6,2,4,3,1];plot(R(1,Q),R(2,Q));
```

**Rotated:**

```
function H(a,b,c,d,e,f) 
C=@cosd;S=@sind;
R=[1,0,0,0;0,C(e),0,-S(e);0,-S(e)*S(f),C(f),-C(e)*S(f);0,S(e)*C(f),S(f),C(e)*C(f)]*
  [C(c)*C(d),-S(c)*C(d),0,S(d);S(c),C(c),0,0;0,0,1,0;-C(c)*S(d),S(c)*S(d),0,C(d)]*
  [C(b),S(a)*S(b),C(a)*S(b),0;0,C(a),-S(a),0;-S(b),S(a)*C(b),C(a)*C(b),0;0,0,0,1]*
  (dec2bin(0:15)'-48.5);
Z=R(3,:)+2;
R=2*R./Z;
Q=[1,2,10,12,11,9,10,14,16,12,4,8,16,15,11,3,7,15,13,9,1,5,13,14,6,8,7,5,6,2,4,3,1];
plot(R(1,Q),R(2,Q));
```

The rotation matrices still consume a lot of bytes, but the Eulerian cycle worked out quite well, reducing the number of vertices visited from <s>96</s> 120 down to 33.

Vertices are generated by taking the 4-bit binary representation of `[0:15]` and considering the msb to be the x-coordinate and the lsb the w-coordinate.

Edit: Pre-multiplying all of the rotation matrices was a nightmare, which is why I didn't use it initially, but pre-multiplying them in pairs saved 41 bytes. <s>Now to look for the optimum combination. :)</s> Multiplying the matrices by threes was worse than no pre-multiplication at all, so I'll be happy with the pair-wise approach.

---

**Output:**

```
H(0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

[image: H(0,0,0,0,0,0)]

```
H(0,0,0,0,0,30)
```

[image: H(0,0,0,0,0,30)]

```
H(30,0,0,0,0,30)
```

[image: H(30,0,0,0,0,30)]

```
H(0,0,0,30,30,30)
```

[image: H(0,0,0,30,30,30)]

```
H(45,45,45,0,0,0)
```

[image: H(45,45,45,0,0,0)]

```
H(45,45,45,45,45,45)
```

[image: H(45,45,45,45,45,45)]

Comment: Edit: I'm stupid. fooled by the same variable everywhere... [Are you sure you don't want the full pre-multiplied matrix? :) https://i.imgur.com/nkM6y6g.png]

Comment: @algmyr Yeah, the fully multiplied matrix came out about twice as long, if I remember correctly.

Comment: This should be more like it, enjoy Maxima's stupid "simplifications": https://i.imgur.com/klkXLPf.png

Comment: To make up for failing miserable at math, here is a more golfed version of your code, 330 bytes: https://paste.ee/p/2GRyJ

Answer (score 14):

### Postscript <del>1075</del> <del>732</del> <del>683</del> <del>640</del> <del>631</del> <del>601</del> <del>590</del> <del>545</del> <del>542</del> <del>526</del> <del>514</del> <del>478</del> 470

Uses [mat.ps](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/xpost/blob/master/data/mat.ps) and [G](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/G).

*Edit:-343* Applied binary-encoding generation of vectors and Eulerian circuit <del>stolen</del> borrowed from other answers. And applied binary-token-strings from the G library.
*Edit:-49* Redefined `sin` `cos` and `neg` to shorter names.
*Edit:-43* Defined short names for sequences `0 0` `0 1` `1 0`.
*Edit:-9* `al` (ie. `aload`) is shorter than `(")@`. Factored 3 calls to `idi` (ie. `idiv`) at the cost of a do-nothing `1 idiv`.
*Edit:-30* Applied *implicit definition block* from G.
*Edit:-10* A few more triply-used sequences.
*Edit:-45* Remove variables `i` `j` `k` `l` `m` `n` for the angles and always define the current angle as `t` and functions of angles use the value of the (global) `t` variable. Defer execution of the code-description of the rotation matrix until its `t` value is ready.
*Edit:-3* Remove `<16>$` ie. `closepath`. And a space.
*Edit:-16* Factor-out array brackets from unit vectors in the rotation matrices (`J` `K` `L` and `M`). Re-apply dropped `mo` for `mod` and `su` for `sub`.
*Edit:-12* In-line the *project-and-draw* function and remove (now empty) enclosing dictionary.
*Edit:-36* Encoded the circuit (ie. the *faces*) in a string.
*Edit:-8* Remove definition of vertices array `V`. Instead, leave on stack and `dup` working copies as needed (once, at first, and again at the end of the loop). Also, translated a few operators from binary-token-strings back to abbreviated names where the BTS gave no savings, so `(I)$` is now `fora` (ie. `forall`). `if du` could be `(T8)$`, but `if du` is clearly a better choice (it's *golf*, not *obfuscation* per se). Also, perform the `scale` *before* `translate`, so translated coordinates can be `3` and `4` instead of `300` and `400`.

```
(mat.ps)run 3(G)run $
t sin
A neg
t cos
0 0
0 1
1 0
2 mu Z 2(!V)@
idi 2 mo .5 su
(>8)$
[F D]
[D E]
[E D]
[D F]

3 4 100(&>88)$(,)# div(<N)#[E 15{[I 1 H I 2 H I 4 H ex 8 H]}fo]E
5{ARGUMENTS 1(XK/)$/t ex d{{J[0 C B 0][0 A C 0]K}{[C 0 A 0]L[B 0
C 0]K}{[C B D][A C D]M K}{[C D A]L M[B D C]}{J[0 C 0 B]M[0 A 0
C]}{J L[D C B][D A C]}}(>K)$[(>?)$]transpose matmul}fo
du(019;:89=?;37?>:26><804<=576451320){48 su get al po{W
Z Y X}{(>3)$}fora X G Y G{li}(D)#{mov}if du}fora(HB)#
```

The `3` `4` and `100` in the first line of the second block are parameters representing center-x, center-y and scale, respectively, of the drawing on the page (center coordinates are scaled by `scale`). (300,400) is roughly the center of US letter-sized paper (612,792) in PS units.

If you can roughly follow postscript, the important bizarre things are the *implicit procedure block* and the encoded operator strings. As shown by comments in the workfile, below, each line of the first block is implicitly named by A, B, C, etc. So, eg. `F E D` would produce `1 0 0 1 0 0`. For the encoded operator strings, anything that is an argument to `$` `#` or `@` is a sequence of operator calls, using the bytes to select operators from the system name table, PLRM 3ed Appendix F. These features and more are available for PostScript with the G library (now includes the mat.ps functions too).

Workfile:

```
(mat.ps)run 3(G)run $
t sin %/A
A neg %/B
t cos %/C
0 0 %/D
0 1 %/E
1 0 %/F
2 mu Z 2(!V)@ %/G  %ad div %add div %108 1 54
idi 2 mo .5 su %idiv mod sub %/H %106 169 51
(>8)$ %/I %exch dup
[F D] %/J
[D E] %/K
[E D] %/L
[D F] %/M


3 4
100(&>88)$ %currentlinewidth exch dup dup %38
(,)#  %scale %139-95=44
div(<N)# %div setlinewidth %54 155-95=60 %translate %173-95=78
%/V
[E 15{[ I
    1 H I
    2 H I
    4 H ex
    8 H]}fo]

E 5{ARGUMENTS 1(XK/)$ %index get cvr %88 75 47
    /t ex d %exch def %62 51
    {{J[0 C B 0][0 A C 0]K} 
     {[C 0 A 0]L[B 0 C 0]K} 
     {[C B D][A C D]M K} 
     {[C D A]L M[B D C]}
     {J[0 C 0 B]M[0 A 0 C]}
     {J L[D C B][D A C]}}
    (>K)$ %exch get %62 75
    [
        (>?)$ %exch exec %62 63
    ]
    transpose matmul
}fo %for
du %dup
%d %def
%{transpose matmul}fora d

%[E 9 11 10 8 9 13 15 11 3 7 15 14 10 2 6 14 12 8 0 4 12 13 5 7 6 4 5 1 3 2 0]
%<0001090b0a08090d0f0b03070f0e0a02060e0c0800040c0d050706040501030200>
%          abcdef
%0123456789:;<=>?
(019;:89=?;37?>:26><804<=576451320)
{48 su get % 169 75 %V (>K)$ %sub %exch get

    al po %aload pop %2 117
    {W Z Y X}{(>3)$ %exch def
    }fora %forall %2 117  62 51 73
    X G
    Y G
    {li}(D)# %stopped
    {mov}
    if du%(T8)$ %if %84 du %dup 56
}
%<49a7a1>$ %forall stroke showpage %73 167-95=72 161-95=66
fora(HB)#
```

Ungolfed and lightly commented:

```
300 400 translate   %roughly center of letter paper
currentlinewidth
100 dup dup scale
div setlinewidth    %scale x100, reduce line-width/100
(mat.ps)run         %load matrix library
ARGUMENTS aload pop{f e d c b a}{exch cvr def}forall  %define args as 
                                 % a,b,etc and convert to real numbers
/m{2 mod .5 sub}def
/P{aload pop{w z y x}{exch def}forall   %P: [x y z w]  project-and-draw  -
    x 2 mul z 2 add div 
    y 2 mul z 2 add div 
    {lineto}stopped{moveto}if %catch(&handle!) nocurrentpoint error in lineto
}bind def
/V[0 1 15{    % generate vectors with a for-loop
    [ exch
        dup m
        1 index 2 idiv m
        2 index 4 idiv m
        4 3 roll 8 idiv m
    ]
}for]
[[[1 0 0 0][0 a cos a sin neg 0][0 a sin a cos 0][0 0 0 1]] 
     [[b cos 0 b sin 0][0 1 0 0][b sin neg 0 b cos 0][0 0 0 1]] 
     [[c cos c sin neg 0 0][c sin c cos 0 0][0 0 1 0][0 0 0 1]] 
     [[d cos 0 0 d sin][0 1 0 0][0 0 1 0][d sin neg 0 0 d cos]]
     [[1 0 0 0][0 e cos 0 e sin neg][0 0 1 0][0 e sin 0 e cos]]
     [[1 0 0 0][0 1 0 0][0 0 f cos f sin neg][0 0 f sin f cos]]]
{transpose matmul} forall def   % apply array of rotations and define

%Eulerian circuit (borrowed and adjusted for 0-based indexing)
[0 1 9 11 10 8 9 13 15 11 3 7 15 14 10 2 6 14 12 8 0 4 12 13 5 7 6 4 5 1 3 2 0]

% the main program!
% on the stack is the Eulerian circuit array
{
    V exch get  %lookup index in (sextuply-transformed) vertex array
    P           %call project-and-draw
} forall
closepath stroke %draw it, don't just think about it

showpage % gs's cmd-line-args option automatically sets -dBATCH,
    % so without a showpage, gs will immediately exit before you
    % can look at the picture :(
```

Some of my outputs are mirror images of the question's examples.

For `gs -- hc.ps 0 0 0 0 0 0`, I get:
[image]

`gs -- hc.ps 0 0 0 0 0 30`
[image]

`gs -- hc.ps 30 0 0 0 0 30`
[image]

`gs -- hc.ps 0 0 0 30 30 30`
[image]

`gs -- hc.ps 45 45 45 0 0 0`
[image]

`gs -- hc.ps 45 45 45 45 45 45`
[image]

Bonus animation I just made with this program.  This image corresponds to the rotation sequence 0 30 60 0 *i* *i*, where i ranges from 0 to 360 by 2.
[image]

Comment: Wow. A PostScript answer for a mathematical problem.

Comment: @TùxCräftîñg There's not actually that much math in this question as long as you can do matrix multiplication easily. And I've wanted to write this program ever since reading A. K. Dewdney's *The Armchair Universe*.

Comment: Added new functions to the G library. Can't use here, but it allows this [307 byte version](https://github.com/luser-dr00g/G/blob/master/hccheat.ps).

Answer (score 8):

## C# + Unity, <s>1060</s> <s>845</s> 835 bytes

C# ≈ Java

Assumes that this function is in a script placed on `MainCamera`.

Edit:
Thanks to @TuukkaX for the suggestions to save 19 bytes
Saved ~200 bytes using the Eulerian cycle.

Golfed:

```
void d(float[]r){transform.position=Vector3.back*2;GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor=Color.black;Vector4[]p=new Vector4[16];Matrix4x4[]m=new Matrix4x4[6];int i=0;for(;i<16;i++)p[i]=new Vector4(i%2,i/2%2,i/4%2,i/8%2)-new Vector4(.5f,.5f,.5f,.5f);int[,]X={{6,8,1,12,7,11},{5,0,0,0,5,10},{10,10,5,15,15,15}};for(i=0;i<6;i++){m[i]=Matrix4x4.identity;r[i]=Mathf.Deg2Rad*r[i];float c=Mathf.Cos(r[i]),s=Mathf.Sin(r[i]);m[i][X[1,i]]=c;m[i][X[2,i]]=c;m[i][X[0,i]]=s;m[i][X[0,i]%4*4+X[0,i]/4]=-s;}for(i=0;i<16;i++)foreach(Matrix4x4 x in m)p[i]=x*p[i];int[]F={0,1,9,11,10,8,9,13,15,11,3,7,15,14,10,2,6,14,12,8,0,4,12,13,5,7,6,4,5,1,3,2,0};LineRenderer l=new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();l.SetVertexCount(33);l.material=new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));l.SetWidth(.03f,.03f);for(i=0;i<33;i++)l.SetPosition(i,p[F[i]]);
```

Newlines + indentation + Full shell:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class h : MonoBehaviour {

    void d(float[]r)
    {
        transform.position=Vector3.back*2.5f;
        GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor=Color.black;
        Vector4[]p=new Vector4[16];
        Matrix4x4[]m=new Matrix4x4[6];
        int i=0;
        for(;i<16;i++)p[i]=new Vector4(i%2,i/2%2,i/4%2,i/8%2)-new Vector4(.5f,.5f,.5f,.5f);
        int[,]X={{6,8,1,12,7,11},{5,0,0,0,5,10},{10,10,5,15,15,15}};
        for (i=0;i<6;i++){
            m[i]=Matrix4x4.identity;
            r[i]=Mathf.Deg2Rad*r[i];
            float c=Mathf.Cos(r[i]);
            float s=Mathf.Sin(r[i]);
            m[i][X[1,i]]=c;
            m[i][X[2,i]]=c;
            m[i][X[0,i]]=s;
            m[i][X[0,i]%4*4+X[0,i]/4]=-s;
        }
        for (i=0;i<16;i++)foreach(Matrix4x4 x in m)p[i]=x*p[i];
        int[]F={0,1,9,11,10,8,9,13,15,11,3,7,15,14,10,2,6,14,12,8,0,4,12,13,5,7,6,4,5,1,3,2,0};
        LineRenderer l=new GameObject().AddComponent<LineRenderer>();
        l.SetVertexCount(33);
        l.material=new Material(Shader.Find("Sprites/Default"));
        l.SetWidth(.03f,.03f);
        for (i=0;i<33;i++)
            l.SetPosition(i,p[F[i]]);
        l.gameObject.tag = "Player";
    }
    public float[] input;
    void Start()
    {
        d(input);
    }
}
```

<s>I couldn't figure out a simple formula for constructing the rotation matrices nor the "faces" which to draw, so that cost a lot of bytes to hard-code.</s> I borrowed the Eulerian cycle from @beaker. Also, Unity built-ins are extremely verbose.

You can verify all test cases [online](https://jediguy13.github.io/hypercube).

Comment: This is the first time I've seen a C# + Unity answer on here. +1

Comment: I think every `0.5f` can be reduced to `.5f` and `0.01f` to `.01f`. I also think that the integer arrays can be separated with a comma instead of saying `int[]` multiple times.

Comment: @Blue Oh, you're right! Haven't used C# for a while so wasn't sure of the last tip.

Comment: @TuukkaX Ignore my previous comment, I can use `int[,]`. Still, thank you.

Comment: You still have an `Vector4(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,0.5f)` which could be reduced to `Vector4(.5f,.5f,.5f,.5f)`.

Comment: Inside your second loop, `float c=Mathf.Cos(r[i]);float s=Mathf.Sin(r[i]);` could be reduced to `float c=Mathf.Cos(r[i]),s=Mathf.Sin(r[i]);`.

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript ES6, 584 bytes

```
f=(...R)=>(P=s=>[...s].map(i=>parseInt(i,16)),C=document.createElement`canvas`,X=C.getContext`2d`,X.translate((C.width=300)/2,(C.height=300)/2),X.lineWidth=0.01,X.scale(100,100),X.beginPath(),P("0267fd9804c8ab915dcefb37546ea2310").map((e,i)=>{[x,y,z]=P("084c2a6e195d3b7f").map(i=>[...(1e3+i.toString(2)).slice(-4)].map(i=>i-0.5)).map(e=>(R.map((R,i,_,M=Math,C=M.cos(r=R*M.PI/180),S=M.sin(r))=>((a,b,s=1)=>[e[a],e[b]]=[C*e[a]-s*S*e[b],s*S*e[a]+C*e[b]])(...[[1,2],[0,2,-1],[0,1],[0,3,-1],[1,3],[2,3]][i])),e))[e];[x,y]=[2*x/(2+z),2*y/(2+z)];i?X.lineTo(x,y):X.moveTo(x,y)}),X.stroke(),C)
```

"Ungolfed":

```
f=(...R)=>(                                                              // function that accepts rotations in the following form: f(a,b,c,d,e,f)
    P=s=>[...s].map(i=>parseInt(i,16)),                                  // function to convert strings to hex-arrays
    V=P("084c2a6e195d3b7f")                                              // vertices encoded as hex values ( [0,1,1,0] -> 6 )
        .map(i=>[...(1e3+i.toString(2)).slice(-4)].map(i=>i-0.5))        // convert hex values to vertices, center the hypercube
        .map(e=>(R.map((R,i,_,M=Math,C=M.cos(r=R*M.PI/180),S=M.sin(r))=> // convert angles to degrees, precalculate sin and cos values
        ((a,b,s=1)=>[e[a],e[b]]=[C*e[a]-s*S*e[b],s*S*e[a]+C*e[b]])       // apply matrix transforms to all vertices
        (...[[1,2],[0,2,-1],[0,1],[0,3,-1],[1,3],[2,3]][i])),e)),        // list of encoded matrix transforms
    C=document.createElement`canvas`,X=C.getContext`2d`,                 // create image to draw on
    X.translate((C.width=300)/2,(C.height=300)/2),                       // setup image dimensions, center transform
    X.lineWidth=0.01,X.scale(100,100),X.beginPath(),                     // setup line, scale the transform and begin drawing
    P("0267fd9804c8ab915dcefb37546ea2310").map((e,i)=>{                  // hypercube edge path indices encoded as hex values
        [x,y,z]=V[e];[x,y]=[2*x/(2+z),2*y/(2+z)];                        // project vertex
        i?X.lineTo(x,y):X.moveTo(x,y)}),X.stroke(),                      // draw vertex
    C)                                                                   // return image
```

See it in action (modified to continuously rotate):

```js
with(document)with(Math)with(document.getElementById`canvas`)with(getContext`2d`){render=()=>{requestAnimationFrame(render);clearRect(0,0,width,height);save();K=performance.now();R=[K*0.01,K*0.02,K*0.03,K*0.04,K*0.05,K*0.06];X=s=>[...s].map(i=>parseInt(i,16));V=X("084c2a6e195d3b7f").map(i=>[...(1e3+i.toString(2)).slice(-4)].map(i=>i-0.5)).map(e=>(R.map((R,i,_,C=cos(r=R*PI/180),S=sin(r))=>((a,b,s=1)=>[e[a],e[b]]=[C*e[a]-s*S*e[b],s*S*e[a]+C*e[b]])(...[[1,2],[0,2,-1],[0,1],[0,3,-1],[1,3],[2,3]][i])),e));translate((width=300)/2,(height=300)/2);lineWidth=0.01;scale(100,100);beginPath();X("0267fd9804c8ab915dcefb37546ea2310").map((e,i)=>{[x,y,z]=V[e];[x,y]=[2*x/(2+z),2*y/(2+z)];i?lineTo(x,y):moveTo(x,y)});stroke();restore();};render();}
```

```html
<html><body><canvas id="canvas"></canvas></body></html>
```

The function returns a HTML5 canvas object, you need to add it to the page by doing `document.body.appendChild(f(0,0,0,0,0,0))` for example.

Currently, the rotations are applied out of order, I'm working on the reordering, but as is, it rotates a hypercube correctly.

Comment: Clever, it took me a while to figure out what you were doing with the matrix transforms. :D Also, I can't get your code snippet to work... it's giving me an unhelpful "Script error." in line 0.

Comment: @beaker What browser are you using? I've tested it on the latest Firefox.

Comment: I'm on Safari 9.1.1. Let me try a different one.

Comment: Yep, Chrome works just fine.

Comment: Safari is crap. Don't use it to check if something works.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>453</s> 415 bytes*

Shortened by using the Eulerian tour and cleaning it all up into a single statement without defining functions in variables. This makes the code slower for some reason. I'm guessing Mathematica reevaluates the functions multiple times now that they are not stored in a variable.

```
Graphics[Line[Table[{2#/(2+#3),2#2/(2+#3)}&@@Map[Dot@@Table[Table[If[n==m==#2||n==m==#,Cos[#3],If[n==#2&&m==#,If[#2==1&&(#==3||#==4),1,-1]Sin[#3],If[n==#&&m==#2,If[#2==1&&(#==3||#==4),-1,1]Sin[#3],If[n==m,1,0]]]],{n,4},{m,4}]&[k[[1]],k[[2]],a[[k[[3]]]]°],{k,{{4,3,6},{4,2,5},{4,1,4},{2,1,3},{3,1,2},{3,2,1}}}].#&,Tuples[{0,1},4]-.5,{1}][[i]],{i,{1,2,10,12,11,9,10,14,16,12,4,8,16,15,11,3,7,15,13,9,1,5,13,14,6,8,7,5,6,2,4,3,1}}]]]
```

* I am counting `°` and `==` as single bytes each since they are represented as  a single character in Mathematica. I think this is fair since lots of languages use weird character encodings.

Ungolfed with comments. The input is hard coded at the top as `a={30,0,0,0,0,30};`. I didn't count that toward my score.

```
a = {45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45};



(* #2,#-th rotation matrix as a funciton of #3 *)
(* Using the \
#-notation saved 6 bytes over the more common function definition \
notation*)
r = 
  Table[If[n == m == #2 || n == m == #, Cos[#3], 
     If[n == #2 && m == #, 
      If[#2 == 1 && (# == 3 || # == 4), 1, -1] Sin[#3], 
      If[n == # && m == #2, 
       If[#2 == 1 && (# == 3 || # == 4), -1, 1] Sin[#3], 
       If[n == m, 1, 0]]]], {n, 4}, {m, 4}] &;

(* Total rotation matrix. Need six of them. Function of the six \
angles to rotate.*)

u = Dot @@ 
     Table[r[k[[1]], 
       k[[2]], \[Degree]*
        a[[k[[3]]]]], {k, {{4, 3, 6}, {4, 2, 5}, {4, 1, 4}, {2, 1, 
         3}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}}}].# &;



(* List of all vertices of the hypercube *)
t = Tuples[{0, 1}, 4];
t -= .5;
v = Map[u, t, {1}];

(*projection*)
p = {2 #/(2 + #3), 2 #2/(2 + #3)} &;

(*Eulerian tour*)

l = Table[
   p @@ v[[i]], {i, {1, 2, 10, 12, 11, 9, 10, 14, 16, 12, 4, 8, 16, 
     15, 11, 3, 7, 15, 13, 9, 1, 5, 13, 14, 6, 8, 7, 5, 6, 2, 4, 3, 
     1}}];
Graphics[Line[l]]
```

`0 0 0 0 0 30`

[image]

`0 0 0 30 30 30`

[image]

`405 10 -14 -8 -9 205`

[image]